# dynamic fetch of localized strings from the server react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, localization

I want to make react-native app multilingual I use react-native-localization library and i use for JSON formats to store translations.
my question is it possible to change JSON strings dynamically for example by adding new language or changing the translation already exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you can use is Code Push here you will be updating the source JS files. if you use a dynamic JSON you will have to request it every time but using codepush you can update the source JSON itself.

More info

https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RN Localization](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization#update--overwrite-locale) setContent method, after using local strings. Check the docs:

> **Update / Overwrite Locale**
>
> You might have default localized in the
>   build but then download the latest localization strings from a server.
>   Use setContent to overwrite the whole object. **NOTE** that this will
>   remove all other localizations if used.

```
strings.setContent({
  en:{
    how:"How do you want your egg todajsie?",
    boiledEgg:"Boiled eggsie",
    softBoiledEgg:"Soft-boiled egg",
    choice:"How to choose the egg"
  }
})
```